# how to layout inside other layout in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout, view, helper

I want to do this:
master.phtml

```
<html>
<body>
   <?php echo $layout;?>
</body>
</html>
```

layout.phtml

```
<div class="grid_3">
   <?php echo $content;?>
</div>
```

view.phtml

```
<?php
   $this->loadCustomLayout('layout.phtml');
?>
```

the content

then... the master are "master.phtml"... in layout goes the content of "layout.phtml"... and... inside the "content" goes the content of "view.phtml"

is possible do this ?

thanks.

Comment: have you considered using the action() helper?

Comment: I want this same functionality.  Did you ever get a good solution?  The answer of using a partial doesn't suffice, as it works differently than we intend, and we cannot nest our views inside of them without some hacky/lengthy code every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a partial to do that, instead of nesting Layouts...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a feature request submitted to the Zend Issue Tracker for this functionality.  There is a patch suggested and provided to Zend_Layout which provides this functionality, but it is not yet part of the Zend Framework.  Go vote for it to be added! 
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8013

You could also try this approach:
http://www.developly.com/creating-3-step-layouts-with-zendlayout

Comment: Incase people were looking for the article, since developly is gone here is an archived copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20120416051651/http://www.developly.com/creating-3-step-layouts-with-zendlayout